# Convert aggregate result to decimal

Tags: apex, soql, map, aggregate, decimal

I need to fetch the AggregateResult 'sett' for each Opportunity in a loop, from a map and convert them into decimals.

I've seen Ariel's solution on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000928HIAQ) post but when I use it, it causes an error

> variable does not exist: decimal

And I'm not sure what the alternative is?

```
   Map<Id,AggregateResult> oppMRFSett = new Map <Id,AggregateResult>
       ([SELECT Opportunity__c Id, SUM(Monthly_Settlement1__c) sett
           FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c 
          WHERE Id IN :newMRFs
          GROUP BY Opportunity__c]);       

    for(Opportunity o : upOpps){

        Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c / forecastDuration.get(o.Id);
        Decimal rmningSett = monthlySett - decimal.valueOf(oppMRFSett.get('sett'))  + '';
```

**UPDATE**

When I adopt Eric's answer (below)

```
    Map<Id,AggregateResult> oppMRFSett = new Map <Id,AggregateResult>();
    oppMRFSett.put('sett', [SELECT Opportunity__c, SUM(Monthly_Settlement1__c) sett
           FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c 
          WHERE Id IN :newMRFs
          GROUP BY Opportunity__c]);   

    for(Opportunity o : upOpps){

          Decimal rmningSett = monthlySett - (decimal)oppMRFSett.get({o.Id}).get('sett');
          system.debug(logginglevel.error,rmningSett);
```

It causes an error

> expecting a right parentheses, found '{'

Comment: Where does upOpps come from? Is there code missing?

Comment: @crmprogdev apologies, I missed your comment, it's a list of Opportunities, there's a lot more code but I've extracted this piece for clarity. Your answer did stop any errors by the way, did you delete it because it didn't include a way to fetch the AggregateResult from the map, using the Opportunity Id as the key?

Comment: You need to replace {Id} with the actual ID of the record. You Map is using 'sett' but that is not a valid ID. so it will not compile either.

Comment: remove the { and } they were just there to indicate a placeholder. In addition you map key is not valid above when you used 'sett' as the map key.

Comment: Yes, I deleted my answer because I didn't understand the relationship once I looked closer at your code.

Comment: @Eric removing the {} stopped any errors. I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by the 'sett' key not being valid, that's what you've used in your answer. What should I use instead?

Comment: @AlexS in your coder the Key is an ID you are using a string oppMRFSett.put('sett',xxxx) This is not a valid ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your map is getting the Aggregate result not the actual sett value

You need to change

```
Decimal rmningSett = monthlySett - decimal.valueOf(oppMRFSett.get('sett'))  + '';
```

to

```
Decimal rmningSett = monthlySett - (decimal)oppMRFSett.get({IDOFRECORD}).get('sett')
```

You should add some checks to ensure it is not null as well.

As an example, this works just fine in dev console:

```
Map<String,AggregateResult> tmp = New Map<String, AggregateResult>();
tmp.put('A',[Select Count(ID)cnt From Account]);
//The next line throws an error Variable does not exist Decimal
//Decimal d = 100 - decimal.valueOf(tmp.get('A').get('cnt'));
//the next line works fine
Decimal d = 100 - (decimal)tmp.get('A').get('cnt');
system.debug(logginglevel.error,d);
```

decimal.valueOf() can not accept an Object which, I think, is why it throws the error variable does not exist decimal. Although the error IMHO should be method does not exist decimal.valueOf(Object)

Comment: Thanks but that causes an error 'Incompatible types since an instance of AggregateResult is never an instance of Decimal.'

Comment: Thats what you should be getting from the code in your original post not what I suggested. Updating with another way

Comment: So for both options, I get 'expecting a right parentheses, found '{'. Does the Id Of Record need to be the Opportunity Id (in the map) or the Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c Id?

Comment: Yes the {IDOFRECORD} was a placeholderer for you to put in the appropriate id

Comment: I'm still getting the "expecting a right parentheses error"..

Comment: You will have to debug your syntax unless you update your question and add your new code. Look at the examples given, READ the error message, review your code then syntax fix the error.

Comment: I've updated my question with the new code.